# Python 2.7: ArcPy cursor while loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, arcpy

I am trying to print entries, specifically high school facility names, from an attribute table using a while loop in Python. I can print out the high school names using a for loop but I am missing something with the while loop.

```
#code using for loop:
import arcpy


try:

    work = raw_input("Enter the full workspace path: ")
    arcpy.env.workspace = work

    fcs = "Schools.shp"

    whereClause = "\"FACILITY\" = 'HIGH SCHOOL'"
    searchCurs = arcpy.SearchCursor(fcs, whereClause, "", "", "")
    row = searchCurs.next()
    row.Name
    for row in searchCurs:
        print row.Name

except Exception as e:
    print "Error: " + str(e)
    print arcpy.GetMessages()
    arcpy.AddError(e)


#code using while loop: 

import arcpy

try:

work = raw_input("Enter the full workspace path: ")
arcpy.env.workspace = work

fcs = "Schools.shp"
field = "FACILITY"

whereClause = "\"FACILITY\" = 'HIGH SCHOOL'"
searchCurs = arcpy.SearchCursor(fcs, whereClause, "", "", "")
row = searchCurs.next()

while row:
    print(row.getValue(field)) 
    row = searchCurs.next


except Exception as e:
    print "Error: " + str(e)
    print arcpy.GetMessages()
    arcpy.AddError(e)
```

The `for` loop script works. How to get the `while` loop to work?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I forgot () after row.next.